# Serializing extra elements into a IDictionary instance with MongoDb's C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I have recently tried to play around with MongoDb's serialization. Basically, I am trying to use the driver's serializer to store my models while at the same time attempting to avoid any dependencies between my well-known model classes and 10gen's MongoDb C# driver (v1.2, if it matters).

This, by itself, is no issue. What is problematic however is that there can be (dynamic) information stored for some of the objects side by side to well-known elements. I could do this by using the `[BsonExtraElements]` attribute, but as I said above, I am trying to avoid coupling my models to MongoDb. Model classes that can have this behaviour, implement a certain interface:

```
public interface IHaveMoreInformation
{
    IDictionary<string, object> Extra { get; set; }
}
```

For this, I have tried to write a custom convention that gets registered in the convention profile at application startup:

```
public sealed class ExtraElementsConvention : IExtraElementsMemberConvention
{
    #region Implementation of IExtraElementsMemberConvention

    public string FindExtraElementsMember(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(IHaveMoreInformation).IsAssignableFrom(type) ? "Extra" : null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is where the problem starts. The driver expects a BsonDocument property (again, I don't want to couple). I was hoping there is a way to work around this and serialize this additional information into an `IDictionary<string,object>` instance.

I am helpful for any ideas to achieve this.

Thanks in advance,
Manny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the driver's inner workings, I've decided to take the matter to mongoDB's issue tracking system. Until now (1.3.1), the driver seems very keen on only accepting a `BsonDocument` property for extra elements; this would effectively couple models to types declared by the driver, which is a bit of a pain when you decide to switch technologies.

The issue is currently being tracked here:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-395

Hopefully this improvement will find its way into 1.4 and help people looking to achieve something similar in the future.

Comment: As a note to others you can now specify the extra elements as a Dictionary as documented here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/